Setting JWT tokens in cookies on 401 in Next js 14 (app) and axios
I have been researching and saw that a lot of people have the same problem. While getting 401 from my backend I need to ask for new (JWT) access token if the refresh token is present and resend original request with new access. I'm storing both tokens inside of cookies (maybe that's the problem). Getting new access is not an issue but storing it inside of cookie is because it requires the server action in Next 14. Since fetching new access token is happening in axios interceptor which is on client I cannot set this token in cookies from interceptor. I'm looking for a work around or some tips on how to deal with this problem so if you have any idea what to do please help.
This is my current setup.
This is my axiosInstance.ts file:
import refreshToken from '@/api/auth/refreshTokens'
import axios, { AxiosError } from 'axios'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/api/v1`,
})

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    async (error: AxiosError) => {
        if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
            const originalRequest = error.config

            if (!originalRequest) {
                return Promise.reject(error)
            }
            if (
                originalRequest.url?.startsWith('/auth/login') ||
                originalRequest.url?.startsWith('/auth/refresh-token')
            ) {
                return Promise.reject(error)
            }
            try {
                const res = await refreshToken()

                if (res.status !== 200 || !res.tokens) {
                    return Promise.reject(error)
                }

                // TODO set access token in cookies somehow

                originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                    `Bearer ${res.tokens?.access_token}`

                return axiosInstance(originalRequest)
            } catch (refreshError) {
                console.log(refreshError)
                return Promise.reject(refreshError)
            }
        }
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
)

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const accessCookie = cookieStore.get('token')
    const refreshCookie = cookieStore.get('refresh_token')

    if (config.url?.startsWith('/auth/refresh-token') && refreshCookie) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${refreshCookie.value}`
        return config
    }
    if (accessCookie) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessCookie.value}`
    }

    return config
})

export default axiosInstance

This is refreshTokens.ts:
'use server'

import LoginDto from '@/models/dto/auth/LoginDto'
import axiosInstance from '@/utils/axiosInstance'
import axios, { AxiosError } from 'axios'

export interface RefreshTokenState {
    status: 200 | 400 | 401 | 500
    message: string
    tokens?: LoginDto
}

/**
 * Function for refreshing access token using refresh token
 */
export default async function refreshTokens(): Promise<RefreshTokenState> {
    try {
        const res = await axiosInstance.post<LoginDto>('/auth/refresh-token')
        if (res.status === 200) {
            // await createSession(res.data.access_token, res.data.refresh_token)
            return {
                status: 200,
                message: 'Token refreshed successfully.',
                tokens: res.data,
            }
        }
        return {
            status: 500,
            message: 'There was a problem refreshing your token.',
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
            const axiosError = error as AxiosError
            if (axiosError.response) {
                const status = axiosError.response.status

                if (status === 401) {
                    return {
                        status: 401,
                        message: 'Token is invalid.',
                    }
                }
                if (status === 400) {
                    return {
                        status: 400,
                        message: 'Refresh token was not present.',
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return {
            status: 500,
            message: 'There was a problem refreshing your token.',
        }
    }
}


This work well but I'm not storing my access token in cookie, so every new fetch will require refetching access token again. All until users goes to another protected page and middlware refetches tokens and stores them inside cookies. That is not good for my project because I have usecases where user is on the same page a long period of time.
This is authenticationMiddleware.ts:
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { CustomMiddleware } from './chain'
import {
    cookieOptions,
    CustomPayload,
    protectedRoutes,
    Role,
} from '@/configs/auth.config'
import { locales } from '@/configs/next-intl.config'
import { base64url, decodeJwt, jwtVerify } from 'jose'
import refreshTokens from '@/api/auth/refreshTokens'
import { DateTime } from 'ts-luxon'
import JwtPayloadSchema from '@/models/schemas/JwtPayloadSchema'

const jwtSecretKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY || ''
const encodedKey = base64url.decode(jwtSecretKey)

export function authenticationMiddleware(middleware: CustomMiddleware): CustomMiddleware {
    return async (
        request: NextRequest,
        event: NextFetchEvent,
        response: NextResponse
    ) => {
        if (pathnameMatches(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
            let token = request.cookies.get('token')?.value
            let newToken = false

            const claims = token ? decodeJwt(token) : undefined

            if (
                !token ||
                (claims && claims.exp && DateTime.now().toMillis() >= claims.exp * 1000)
            ) {
                const res = await refreshTokens()
                if (res.status !== 200 || !res.tokens) {
                    return NextResponse.redirect(
                        new URL(
                            `/login?redirect=${request.nextUrl.pathname}`,
                            request.url
                        )
                    )
                }
                token = res.tokens.access_token
                newToken = true
            }

            try {
                const { payload } = (await jwtVerify(token, encodedKey, {
                    algorithms: ['HS256'],
                })) as { payload: CustomPayload }

                validatePayload(payload)

                if (!hasRequiredRole(request.nextUrl.pathname, payload.roles)) {
                    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/forbidden', request.url))
                }
                if (newToken) {
                    response.cookies.set('token', token, cookieOptions('access'))
                }
            } catch (error) {
                return NextResponse.redirect(
                    new URL(`/login?redirect=${request.nextUrl.pathname}`, request.url)
                )
            }
        }
        return middleware(request, event, response)
    }
}

const pathnameMatches = (pathname: string): boolean => {
    const localeMatch = locales.find(locale => pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}`))
    if (localeMatch) {
        pathname = pathname.replace(`/${localeMatch}`, '')
    }
    if (!pathname.endsWith('/')) {
        pathname += '/'
    }
    return Object.keys(protectedRoutes).some(route => pathname.startsWith(route))
}

const hasRequiredRole = (pathname: string, roles: Role[]): boolean => {
    if (!pathname.endsWith('/')) {
        pathname += '/'
    }

    const matchingRoute = Object.keys(protectedRoutes).find(routePattern =>
        pathname.startsWith(routePattern)
    )

    if (!matchingRoute) {
        return true
    }

    const requiredRoles = protectedRoutes[matchingRoute]

    return roles.some(role => requiredRoles.includes(role))
}

const validatePayload = (payload: CustomPayload) => {
    JwtPayloadSchema.parse(payload)
}

I have also tried using route handler that I call from my interceptor but then I also didn't succeed in storing access token in cookies. What is workaround for that?
